# Ajuda com posicionamento de divs quando chegar em uma determinada media query

Tags: html, css

Boa noite...
Estou fazendo uns teste simples aqui para começar uma projeto, só que não estou conseguindo fazer os posicionamento das divs do jeito que eu quero. Gostaria de saber se alguém já fez algum igual e se poderia me ajudar.

tem que ter duas sidebar e um conteúdo no meio (todos são divs) como mostrado na figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que quando chega-se a uma determinada media query (@media) ela ficasse nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As cores deu uma bagunçada rsrs mas da pra entender,
preciso que as sidebar vão para baixo.

Eu não tenho código ainda, só estou no começo. O único teste que fiz eu fiz como position, só que não ficou muito bom.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

**Com Display:Flex**

Tem uma solução simples para isso usando um `container flex` para colocar as `divs` com `flex-grow:1` para ficarem divididas igualmente. Depois disso, na `div` do centro, quando chegar no `@media` que vc definir, vc coloca o `flex-basis` dela para `100%` e `order` para `-1` assim ela "pular" para a primeira posição ocupando a linha inteira, e deixando as outra `divs` na linha de baixo tb divididas igualmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima. **Exiba em tela toda para ver o grid mudando :)**

```css
.centro {background: tomato;}
.esq {background: yellowgreen;}
.dir {background: aqua;}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div{
 flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px)  {
 .container .centro {
  order: -1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="esq">esq</div>
 <div class="centro">centro</div>
 <div class="dir">dir</div>
</div>
```

Leia mais sobre flex nessa documentação https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/flex

---

**Com Display:Grid**

Usando `display:grid` tb é muito tranquilo de fazer, vc pode usar a propriedade `grid-area` e `grid-template-areas` para "nomear" cada div e definir como eles vai se dispor em cara `@media`. Então o template ficaria como abaixo para vc ter uma ideia...

```
grid-template-areas:      "esq centro dir";

@media 768px  {

    grid-template-areas: "centro centro" "esq dir";

}
```

Segue o código completo:

```css
.centro {
    background: tomato;
    grid-area: centro;
}
.esq {
    background: yellowgreen;
    grid-area: esq;
}
.dir {
    background: aqua;
    grid-area: dir;
}

.container {
 display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "esq centro dir";
}


@media (max-width: 768px)  {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas: 
          "centro centro" 
          "esq dir";
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="esq">esq</div>
 <div class="centro">centro</div>
 <div class="dir">dir</div>
</div>
```